# Android - youtube api search by keyword does not work

Tags: java, android, android-activity, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using this example -

[serach by keyword - youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword)

when the app trying the execute the following line it crashes:

```
 SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
```

This is the exception:

> 10-23 22:32:17.186: I/Adreno-EGL(14500): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
>   10-23 22:32:17.226: D/OpenGLRenderer(14500): Enabling debug mode 0
>   10-23 22:32:18.167: I/System.out(14500): search
>   10-23 22:32:19.169: D/dalvikvm(14500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 189K, 3% free 9309K/9532K, paused 21ms, total 22ms
>   10-23 22:32:20.840: I/System.out(14500): query !!! ghh
>   10-23 22:32:21.111: D/dalvikvm(14500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 184K, 3% free 9638K/9856K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
>   10-23 22:32:21.121: W/ContextImpl(14500): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517 com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e:-1 com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a:-1 
>   10-23 22:32:21.161: I/System.out(14500): ***************************************************
>   10-23 22:32:21.241: D/dalvikvm(14500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 374K, 5% free 9776K/10184K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
>   10-23 22:32:21.271: W/System.err(14500): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   10-23 22:32:21.271: W/System.err(14500):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>   10-23 22:32:21.271: W/System.err(14500):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   10-23 22:32:21.271: W/System.err(14500):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   10-23 22:32:21.271: W/System.err(14500):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   10-23 22:32:21.271: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>   10-23 22:32:21.271: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.wetago.service.YoutubeService.getSearchResultList(YoutubeService.java:62)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.wetago.YoutubeResultListActivity$VideoListFragment.initVideoList(YoutubeResultListActivity.java:178)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.wetago.YoutubeResultListActivity.onCreate(YoutubeResultListActivity.java:75)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/System.err(14500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: D/AndroidRuntime(14500): Shutting down VM
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: W/dalvikvm(14500): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4158aba8)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500): Process: com.android.wetago, PID: 14500
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.wetago/com.android.wetago.YoutubeResultListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: list == null
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: list == null
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.java:2283)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at com.android.wetago.YoutubeResultListActivity$VideoListFragment.initVideoList(YoutubeResultListActivity.java:179)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at com.android.wetago.YoutubeResultListActivity.onCreate(YoutubeResultListActivity.java:75)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>   10-23 22:32:21.281: E/AndroidRuntime(14500):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple network on main thread exception. You should do your API calls inside an AsyncTask.

Checkout [YouTube Direct Lite for Android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android) for example.